# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Poisson as array

Tags: php, fatal-error

hi guys i get that error on this code, i have this function in the class Markets.php

```
public function getUnder($line){
        $under = 0;
        for($i=0; $i<= floor($line) ;$i++){
            for ($j=0; $j<= (floor($line) - $i);$j++){
                    $under = $under + $this->poisson_tab[$i][$j];
            }
        }
        return $under;
    }
```

i'm trying to use it like this:

```
$get_markets = new Markets($tab_poisson);

echo "Under 2.5 -> ".(1/$get_markets->getUnder(2.5))."</br>";
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the Markets class?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but with the information you gave I would guess that ..

`$this->poisson_tab[$i][$j]` should not be referenced as an array, it should be referenced as an object.. like `$this->poisson_tab->$i->$j` or `$this->poisson_tab[$i]->$j` depending on the rest of your code.